# Como enviar parametro en event JSF

Tags: java, jsf

Tengo el siguiente event de tipo `preRenderView` para ejecutar un método antes de cargar la pagina:

```
<f:event listener="#{aprobacionFlujoController.preRender}" type="preRenderView" />
```

Necesito enviar un parámetro hacia ese listener, ¿cuál es la mejor manera de hacerlo? Probé de la siguiente manera:

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:event listener="#{aprobacionFlujoController.preRender}" type="preRenderView" />
    <f:attribute name="myid" value="true" />
</f:metadata>
```

Y en el controller

```
public void retrieveData(ComponentSystemEvent event) {
String id = (String) event.getComponent().getAttributes().get("myid");}
```

Pero `getAttributes()` llega vacío.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`f:attribute` sólo se aplica a componentes [que extienden `UIComponent`](https://javaserverfaces.java.net/nonav/docs/2.0/vdldocs/facelets/f/attribute.html); `f:metadata` no es uno de ellos.

Lo que puedes hacer es:

- Si el valor está fijo (como parece en el código), usar `c:set` de JSTL:
- Si se pasa por parámetro definirlo con `f:viewParam`:

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta